# jquery firstChild.data equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an equivalient of the firstChild.data in JQuery?

Given the following HTML :

```
<p id='test'>Hello<span>world</span>/<p>
```

the below javascipt will return : "Hello"

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild.data
```

the given JQuery will return : `Hello< span>world</span>`

```
$('#test').text()
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want this? Using jQuery is a priori much slower than native DOM. If you just already have jQuery object, you can retrieve native DOM object, and then use DOM: `$('#test').get(0).firstChild.data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a text node, so you can make use of `.contents`:

```
$("#test").contents().first().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $('#test').contents()[0].nodeValue;
```

`contents()` helps you to get text node.